# Return Maximum Value along with day + time value grouped by month

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by, max

Using MS-SQL 2012. Having a real puzzle trying to retrieve specific datafields from a large climatology dataset.

I have stripped this large raw data file down to a temp table called #max_temp which correctly pulls back the max value for each day along with the time it occurred and day/month value for reference:

```
monthid month   day time    current_temp
1       12     24   12:45   9.1
1       12     25   12:25   8.3
1       12     26   23:55   8.6
1       12     27   00:00   8.6
1       12     28   13:15   5.9
1       12     29   12:50   5
1       12     30   13:32   6.3
1       12     31   12:49   6.9
2        1      1   23:59   12
2        1      2   01:12   12.7
2        1      3   03:55   6.2
```

What I want to retrieve is an output grouped by monthID, so returning:

```
monthid     month   day time    current_temp
    1       12      24  12:45   9.1
    2       1       9   20:04   15.1  <<*not shown in above sample*>>
```

From looking at other similar questions I have tried the following the code but not getting to the end solution or the query fails.

```
select * 
from (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by t.monthid, t.time order by t.current_temp desc) as rn
from #max_temp t) x
where rn=1
order by monthid asc
```

or

```
select monthid, day, time, current_temp 
from #max_temp
where current_temp= (select max(current_temp) from #max_temp group by MonthID, day, time)
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Elliot.

Comment: If @SqlZim answered this for you, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `t.time` from the `partition by` like so:

```
select * 
from (
  select t.*, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by t.monthid order by t.current_temp desc) as rn
  from #max_temp t
  ) x
where rn=1
order by monthid asc
```

Having `time` in the partition would give you the greatest value for `current_temp` for each `monthid` and `time`, but since you just want the greatest `current_temp` for each `monthid`, remove `time` from that expression.